# Why is my object moving out of place during a Cloth Simulation?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am using a Cloth Simulation on a plane to create a cushion. However, when I apply any form of Pressure it moves out of position. Below are images of the setting, the first frame and the second frame.

[image: Cloth Settings]

[image: Frame 1]

[image: Frame 2]

Download link for blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rJHK0OowcqgRXycC6CE3E25_-qoBLOiF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi soup, I think the pressure you have set is way too much. Try decreasing it.

Comment: I tried setting it to a fractional number and yet it still moves it.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (the useful part of it): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: done now with google drive

Comment: there is no plane as the screenshot in the blend file

Comment: Fixed Sanbaldo.

Comment: search in google for "how to create a pillow in blender" -> lots of video tutorials out there

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find the reason as to why the the origin kept moving? It's driving me crazy :(